# Table only works when put with nolock

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table only show results when I put with nolock.

When I put `select * from mytable`, the query is not completed and keep running...

But when I put `select * from mytable with (nolock)`, the result appears and the query runs ok.

Anyone have an Idea the "why" or where to start searching this issue?

obs: the database is new, created a few days ago; is a homolog database with less than 10 users using the system (created in asp.net mvc with EF).

I have a query that normally help me when exists lock in database, but nothing appear with it:

```
SELECT es.session_id AS session_id
,COALESCE(es.original_login_name, '') AS login_name
,COALESCE(es.host_name,'') AS hostname
,COALESCE(es.last_request_end_time,es.last_request_start_time) AS last_batch
,es.status
,COALESCE(er.blocking_session_id,0) AS blocked_by
,COALESCE(er.wait_type,'MISCELLANEOUS') AS waittype
,COALESCE(er.wait_time,0) AS waittime
,COALESCE(er.last_wait_type,'MISCELLANEOUS') AS lastwaittype
,COALESCE(er.wait_resource,'') AS waitresource
,coalesce(db_name(er.database_id),'No Info') as dbid
,COALESCE(er.command,'AWAITING COMMAND') AS cmd
,sql_text=st.text
,transaction_isolation =
    CASE es.transaction_isolation_level
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Read Uncommitted'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Read Committed'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot'
END
,COALESCE(es.cpu_time,0) 
    + COALESCE(er.cpu_time,0) AS cpu
,COALESCE(es.reads,0) 
    + COALESCE(es.writes,0) 
    + COALESCE(er.reads,0) 
    + COALESCE(er.writes,0) AS physical_io
,COALESCE(er.open_transaction_count,-1) AS open_tran
,COALESCE(es.program_name,'') AS program_name
,es.login_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions es
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec ON es.session_id = ec.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests er ON es.session_id = er.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON es.security_id = sp.sid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks ota ON es.session_id = ota.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_threads oth ON ota.worker_address = oth.worker_address
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) AS st
where es.is_user_process = 1 
  and es.session_id <> @@spid
ORDER BY es.session_id
```

Comment: If you need to use `NOLOCK` it means some other query is executing that's taken exclusive locks on at least one row for a long time, probably as part of a long running transaction. Use the Activity Monitor in SSMS to see which connection and query is blocking yours

Comment: Then somebody or something is inserting/updating/doing stuff to that table.

Comment: You can avoid such issues without `NOLOCK` which actually means `read dirty data while taking excessive locks yourself` with the `READPAST` hint to bypass locked rows, or by using the SNAPSHOT transaction isolation level instead of READ COMMITED.

Comment: run [**sp_WhoIsActive**](http://whoisactive.com/) and see who has locks on that table

Answer (score 0):

The simple explanation would be, you are required to use `NOLOCK` to get query executed, that means at least one transaction is open and running on that particular table with exclusive lock.

`NOLOCK` hint do the dirty read and ignores all the locks on the table.

If you are not getting log for the issue then, try to take database in single user mode, which will break all existing connections for other users and then execute your query without `NOLOCK` and then check whether it successfully executes or not. If YES, then the issue is only that some transactions are active on that DB by other users.

Also, you can execute `ROLLBACK TRANS` or `COMMIT TRANS` to end any transaction if it is open on your session.

`READPAST` hint could be a solution, but it will not resolve your root cause.